# Error with permission in Chef routine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, capistrano, chef-infra, unicorn

I have the following Chef routine to generate a script to start/stop a unicorn daemon.

However I always get a Permission denied when Capistrano execute this file. What I'm doing wrong with its permissions?

```
# recipes/default.rb

template "/etc/init.d/unicorn_#{node['pod']['app_name']}" do
  owner node['pod']['user']
  group node['pod']['user']
  mode 777
  source "unicorn_init.erb"
  variables( :app_name => node['pod']['app_name'], :user => node['pod']['user'] )
end
```

---

```
# templates/default/unicorn_init.rb

#!/bin/sh
set -e

# Feel free to change any of the following variables for your app:
TIMEOUT=${TIMEOUT-60}
APP_ROOT=/home/<%= @user %>/apps/<%= @app_name %>/current
PID=/var/run/unicorn/unicorn_<%= @app_name %>.pid
CMD="cd $APP_ROOT; bundle exec unicorn -D -c $APP_ROOT/config/unicorn.rb -E production"
AS_USER=<%= @user %>
set -u

OLD_PIN="$PID.oldbin"

sig () {
  test -s "$PID" && su -c "kill -$1 `cat $PID`" - $AS_USER
}

oldsig () {
  test -s $OLD_PIN && sudo -c "kill -$1 `cat $OLD_PIN`" - $AS_USER
}

run () {
  if [ "$(id -un)" = "$AS_USER" ]; then
    eval $1
  else
    su -c "$1" - $AS_USER
  fi
}

case "$1" in
start)
  sig 0 && echo >&2 "Already running" && exit 0
  run "$CMD"
  ;;
stop)
  sig QUIT && exit 0
  echo >&2 "Not running"
  ;;
force-stop)
  sig TERM && exit 0
  echo >&2 "Not running"
  ;;
restart|reload)
  sig HUP && echo reloaded OK && exit 0
  echo >&2 "Couldn't reload, starting '$CMD' instead"
  run "$CMD"
  ;;
upgrade)
  if sig USR2 && sleep 2 && sig 0 && oldsig QUIT
  then
    n=$TIMEOUT
    while test -s $OLD_PIN && test $n -ge 0
    do
      printf '.' && sleep 1 && n=$(( $n - 1 ))
    done
    echo

    if test $n -lt 0 && test -s $OLD_PIN
    then
      echo >&2 "$OLD_PIN still exists after $TIMEOUT seconds"
      exit 1
    fi
    exit 0
  fi
  echo >&2 "Couldn't upgrade, starting '$CMD' instead"
  run "$CMD"
  ;;
reopen-logs)
  sig USR1
  ;;
*)
  echo >&2 "Usage: $0 <start|stop|restart|upgrade|force-stop|reopen-logs>"
  exit 1
  ;;
esac
```

As you can see, it doesn't set the correct mode for the file:

```
[2013-05-27T20:42:00+02:00] INFO: Processing template[/etc/init.d/unicorn_pod] action create (pod::default line 38)
[2013-05-27T20:42:00+02:00] INFO: template[/etc/init.d/unicorn_pod] owner changed to 1001
[2013-05-27T20:42:00+02:00] INFO: template[/etc/init.d/unicorn_pod] group changed to 110
[2013-05-27T20:42:00+02:00] INFO: template[/etc/init.d/unicorn_pod] mode changed to 1411

 ** [out :: localhost] -r----x--t 1 deployer deployer  1453 2013-05-27 17:48 unicorn_pod
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the [docs](http://docs.opscode.com/resource_template.html). Mode should be octal or string:

```
template "/etc/init.d/unicorn_#{node['pod']['app_name']}" do
  [...]
  mode 0777 #or mode "777"
  [...]
end
```